# Pandas: Finding mean value in multi-level index

Tags: pandas

I have the following code just multi-indexing some ag data:

```
df_corn_mean = df_corn.set_index(['Year','Value'])
df_corn_mean
```

It results in this:

```
                County        Commodity
Year    Value       
2016    171.2   BARTHOLOMEW   CORN
        180.1   BOONE         CORN
        190.6   CLINTON       CORN
        178.9   DECATUR       CORN
        179.5   HAMILTON      CORN
```

There are several more years.  I want the mean of the values per year.  I've tried to groupby, which I thought was the right approach, but I'm having trouble.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you also just got to 15 rep!  congrats!  that means you are now able to up up-vote.  Feel free to up vote all answers to your questions that were helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `'Value'` in the index.  Not a big deal, just increases the number of steps needed to get the mean of it via `groupby`.

I'd go back a step and do

```
df_corn.groupby('Year').Value.mean()

Year
2016    180.06
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

You could also do the following if it suited your purpose more

```
df_corn_mean = df_corn.set_index(['Year', 'Value'], drop=False)
```

That `drop=False` leaves the columns you set as the index in the dataframe proper as well.  That means you can still easily grab them for `groupby` calculations

Now:

```
df_corn_mean.groupby(level='Year').Value.mean()
```

Comment: Great!  Just what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs you either want to reduce data (see [@piRSquared solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43214922/5741205)) or not:

```
In [48]: df_corn.groupby('Year')['Value'].transform('mean')
Out[48]:
0    180.06
1    180.06
2    180.06
3    180.06
4    180.06
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```