# Pandas replace nan with mean of multi level column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi level dataset. I have to replace NaNs in multiple columns with mean value for particular categories that are coming another column.

The data is like this:

```html
<table class="tg">
<th>Name</th>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
  <tr>
    <td>Cat 1</th>
    <td>10</th>
    <td>20</th>
    <td></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cat 1</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>5<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cat 2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cat 2</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to fill the empty cells of each column with the mean value for the corresponding value in the name column.

I have figured out how to find the mean of a multi index column from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43214922) link.
and I am aware about the `fillna` function to fill up NaN values. But how to use them in my scenario?

Comment: Is this the data or is this the output of the data to html?  It would be easier if you gave something to work with like `df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[np.nan,6,10]})`.

Comment: @JeffTilton I basically imported the data from an Excel sheet. And the output is basically an illustration of the real data. This has nothing to do with HTML. I just used HTML because I thought that it would be easier to denote tables using HTML

Comment: Please give a sample of the data to make it easier